# How does Storm manage sharing data on cluster mode?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-storm

recently I'm developing some timing tools for storm topology, but I still have some questions about sharing data in storm cluster:

1. If a component(spout/bolt) is configured with more than one executors per worker, say the worker number is one, the parallelism_hint of the component is 3 and the task number uses default setting(i.e. 1), does that mean there are 3 instances of the component in the worker? If not, should the field of the component be used in a synchronized block?
2. If an additional thread named "athread" is created in a component(within `prepare()` or `open()` method), how many "athread" instances are there in the storm cluster?
3. As [Understanding the Parallelism of a Storm Topology](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html) says, a worker is a separate process, and a worker process executes a subset of a topology. Does that mean global variables (such as public static fields or other static variables) of the topology can only be shared in one worker?
4. If a spout's parallelism_hint is configured greater than 1, and there is a `Utils.sleep(1000)` sentence in `nextTuple()` method, does that mean the number of emitted tuples of the spout is equal to the executors'(threads) number of the spout every second?

Thanks very much.

Comment: If the paralelism_hint is set to 3 then you will have 3 instances of your bolt spread across workers. For instance, if you have one worker, then you will have 3 instances into the same JVM. However, if you have 3 workers you will have one instance per JVM. So if you create a new thread into the open()/prepare() method you will have as many threads as bolt instances. Yes, static fields are shared among components running on the same worker.

Comment: Yes, you are right but by default Storm instantiates for a specific component as many instances as executors  if NumTask is not set.

Comment: @fhuz parallelism hint specify the number of executor aka threads to be allocated not the instance. Your statement holds true only in case you do not configure no of tasks as in that case storm will run 1 tasks per executor (setting parallelism hint = 2 will create 2 tasks by default unless configured explicitly), otherwise it is possible to run a component having one tasks with multiple executors.

Comment: yes true . sorry I missed the comment before updating mine

Comment: Thanks @fhuz . But I still wonder about what would happened to the instances of the component and the related threads it created when a topology is rebalanced?

Answer (score 2):

1) Setting parallelism hint = 3 will ask storm to allocate 3 executors ( Threads ) and will create 3 tasks by default( Please note if you do not explicitly configure the number of tasks storm will run one tasks per executor by default) for that component. If you set the no task = 1 , then three threads will be operating on the same component instance.

2) Assuming you are running with default settings ( 1 executor & 1 task/component) it will create one single instance of that thread object as the prepare/open method will only be called once.

3) Static variables will be shared by all the instances of a component within a given worker.

4) Not sure what exactly you mean, if you are running with multiple executors and one tasks then when Thread-A is sleeping another Thread-B might be processing the tuple

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ask the fourth question to make sure that whether the emitting frequency of the spout is proportional to the number of executors, as I used to think that a thread sleep could make an accurate control for the stream emitting before I know that an executor is a thread.

Comment: consider this, if you have one executor and multiple tasks , then it won't increase the level of parallelism as tasks always run serially. Now if you have multiple executors/thread and multiple tasks for any component then they will run in parallel... a task in a topology is static and can't be altered but during rebalance you can change the number of executors and thus tunning the topology throughput.

Comment: if you are tyring to do some thing in a fixed interval you might want to look at [storm's tick tuple](https://storm.apache.org/2012/08/02/storm080-released.html#tick-tuples)

Comment: I know tick tuple works, but tick tuple can only be used for doing something at a fixed interval. My problem is that I need to do some statistic things in B bolt after A blot had finished its work and sent a "time to do it" signal, while the signal cannot be sent to all executors of B bolt under a parallel circumstance. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: its tricky to determine when a bolt is `done` in a streaming scenario. as you should expect the topology be running contineously. One way I could think of is store the processed tuple in bolt A in a collection till you decide its done and then emit all the tuple in that collection in once.You can also look at trident which process tuples in batch and allows you to confiure the batch size.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind words. Trident is really useful for most statistic jobs, but my topology is a little different. I tried a lot of ways to solve the problem until I met [CoordinatedBolt](https://storm.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/coordination/CoordinatedBolt.html), a very interesting bolt. I designed an intermediate bolt like CoordinatedBolt to send the signal, and now it works!